# Shopware 6. Plugin Admin Module Not Showing in menu

Tags: shopware6

I am developing a plugin, and I want to add a custom admin module.

I added the module/swag-bundle to start.

I created:

src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/swag-bundle/index.js

```js
    import './page/swag-bundle-list';
    import './page/swag-bundle-detail';
    import './page/swag-bundle-create';
    import deDE from './snippet/de-DE.json';
    import enGB from './snippet/en-GB.json';
    
    const { Module } = Shopware;
    
    Module.register('swag-bundle', {
        type: 'plugin',
        name: 'Bundle',
        title: 'swag-bundle.general.mainMenuItemGeneral',
        description: 'sw-property.general.descriptionTextModule',
        color: '#FFD700',
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
    
        snippets: {
            'de-DE': deDE,
            'en-GB': enGB
        },
    
        routes: {
            list: {
                component: 'swag-bundle-list',
                path: 'list'
            },
            detail: {
                component: 'swag-bundle-detail',
                path: 'detail/:id',
                meta: {
                    parentPath: 'swag.bundle.list'
                }
            },
            create: {
                component: 'swag-bundle-create',
                path: 'create',
                meta: {
                    parentPath: 'swag.bundle.list'
                }
            }
        },
    
        navigation: [{
            id: 'swag-bundle-example',
            path: 'swag.bundle.list',
            parent: 'sw-extension',
            label: 'swag-bundle.general.mainMenuItemGeneral',
            icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
            position: 100
        }]
    });
```

src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js

```
import './module/swag-bundle';
```

Image of code:

[image]
But it does not appear in the admin menu.

that could be happening?

**second try**

custom/plugins/my-plugin/src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js

```
import './module/blog-post';
```

custom/plugins/my-plugin/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/blog-post/index.js

```
Module.register('blog-post', {
    type: 'plugin',
    title: 'blog-post.general.title',
    description: 'blog-post.general.descriptionTextModule',
    color: '#ff68b4',
    icon: 'regular-content',
    snippets: {
        'en-GB': enGB,
        'de-DE': deDE
    },

    routes: {
        create: {
            component: 'blog-post-create',
            path: 'create',
            meta: {
                privilege: 'blog_post.creator',
                parentPath: 'blog.post.index',
            },
        }
    },

    navigation: [{
        id: 'blog.post.index',
        label: 'blog-post.general.mainMenuItemList',
        color: '#ff68b4',
        path: 'blog.post.index',
        icon: 'regular-content',
        position: 10,
        parent: 'sw-content'
    }],
```

});

custom/plugins/my-plugin/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/blog-post/page/blog-post-create/index.js

```
import template from './blog-post-create.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.extend('blog-post-create', {
    template
    
});
```

And the template is

```
{% block blog_post_create %}
    <h1> Hola </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I try rebuild the administration
Clear shopware cache
Clear browser cache
Private Navigation

Nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a valid `parent` for your new menu entry, [adding new menu entries on the root level of the navigation is not allowed](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-menu-entry#menu-entry-in-category). If you want to offer your plugin in the community store, I think there is a rule that all new menu entries must be descendants of `sw-extension`. If it's a private plugin you should also be able to choose other parents such as `sw-catalogue`.

Comment: I have changed:

navigation: [{
        id: 'swag-bundle-example',
        path: 'swag.bundle.list',
        parent: 'sw-extension',
        label: 'swag-bundle.general.mainMenuItemGeneral',
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
        position: 100
    }]

but still not showing

Comment: I have cleaned the cache too.

php bin/console cache:clear

Comment: i have added a image of code structure

Comment: Try rebuilding the administration and reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: Btw in the screenshot the path is wrong. `'swag.bundle.list'` was correct.

Comment: I have rebuild with ./bin/build-administration.sh and reinstalled the module many times.

Nothing works

Comment: i logout and login admin too

Comment: I have installed other plugins that also have admin modules and none appear in the menu...

Comment: Clear the browser cache or try an incognito tab. Sounds like you're receiving cached assets.

Comment: Yes, I clear the cache and de other plugin show admin plugin. Then, i copy de app folder from the other plugin for mine Resources folder and...NOT SHOW....

Comment: I added code with second try, more easily, but still dont works

Answer (score 0):

After rebuilding the administration you have to check the console for an error.
If it shows doesn't any error, make sure that you correctly import the js module in the main.js file.